# R Bioconductor cannot find keys() function for ChipDb class

Tags: r, bioconductor

Hello Bioconductor users,

I am playing around with ChipDb classes, in particular the illuminaHumanv4.db package. I am simply trying to create a table of annotations from that db using the select() method, as described in the help section.

I believe the only library needed to test this is

```
library("illuminaHumanv4.db")
```

The cols() function works fine

```
    > cols(illuminaHumanv4.db)
 [1] "PROBEID"      "ENTREZID"     "PFAM"         "IPI"          "PROSITE"      "ACCNUM"       "ALIAS"        "CHR"          "CHRLOC"       "CHRLOCEND"   
[11] "ENZYME"       "MAP"          "PATH"         "PMID"         "REFSEQ"       "SYMBOL"       "UNIGENE"      "ENSEMBL"      "ENSEMBLPROT"  "ENSEMBLTRANS"
[21] "GENENAME"     "UNIPROT"      "GO"           "EVIDENCE"     "ONTOLOGY"     "GOALL"        "EVIDENCEALL"  "ONTOLOGYALL"  "OMIM"         "UCSCKG"
```

The keytypes() function works fine too

```
    > keytypes(illuminaHumanv4.db)
 [1] "ENTREZID"     "PFAM"         "IPI"          "PROSITE"      "ACCNUM"       "ALIAS"        "CHR"          "CHRLOC"       "CHRLOCEND"    "ENZYME"      
[11] "MAP"          "PATH"         "PMID"         "REFSEQ"       "SYMBOL"       "UNIGENE"      "ENSEMBL"      "ENSEMBLPROT"  "ENSEMBLTRANS" "GENENAME"    
[21] "UNIPROT"      "GO"           "EVIDENCE"     "ONTOLOGY"     "GOALL"        "EVIDENCEALL"  "ONTOLOGYALL"  "PROBEID"      "OMIM"         "UCSCKG"
```

However, when I run the keys() function, I am getting the following error

```
    > keys(illuminaHumanv4.db)
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘keys’ for signature ‘"ChipDb"’
```

According to the documentation, the ChipDb class should inherit this function from the AnnotationDb class. This causes a error when I try to run the select() function, since one of the arguments to pass is generated by the keys() function.

I have updated my environment (R 3.0.1, bioconductor 2.12) and all my packages and here is my sessionInfo()

```
    R version 3.0.1 (2013-05-16)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
 [1] grid      splines   parallel  stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] hgu95av2.db_2.9.0         BiocInstaller_1.10.2      gplots_2.11.3             KernSmooth_2.23-10        caTools_1.14              gdata_2.13.2             
 [7] gtools_3.0.0              hash_2.2.6                shiny_0.6.0               GO.db_2.9.0               illuminaHumanv4.db_1.18.0 org.Hs.eg.db_2.9.0       
[13] RSQLite_0.11.4            DBI_0.2-7                 annotate_1.38.0           AnnotationDbi_1.22.6      genefilter_1.42.0         WGCNA_1.27-1             
[19] doParallel_1.0.3          iterators_1.0.6           foreach_1.4.1             MASS_7.3-27               reshape_0.8.4             plyr_1.8                 
[25] cluster_1.14.4            Hmisc_3.12-2              survival_2.37-4           flashClust_1.01-2         dynamicTreeCut_1.21       impute_1.34.0            
[31] Biobase_2.20.1            BiocGenerics_0.6.0       

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] AnnotationForge_1.2.2 bitops_1.0-5          codetools_0.2-8       compiler_3.0.1        digest_0.6.3          httpuv_1.0.6.3        IRanges_1.18.2       
 [8] lattice_0.20-15       Rcpp_0.10.4           RJSONIO_1.0-3         stats4_3.0.1          tools_3.0.1           XML_3.95-0.2          xtable_1.7-1
```

Let me know if anyone has run in the same problem recently.

Thank you!

Comment: There are some BioC users around here, but you might get a wider audience if you edited the question to include the library() calls needed to set this question up as reproducible. Most of us have no idea where to find these functions.

Comment: Thanks DWin. I added the library() call on top.

Comment: Well, I ran into errors and needed to update to the current version of R (version 3.0.1 Patched). When I did I get no error. I get 48106 + 1 keys. You don't seem to have Patched version. Maybe a reboot with loading just the required packages would be sensible? You have 11 more packages loaded than I do at the moment.

Comment: It did it! I think the 3.0.1 Patched version was the key, because I had done an R reboot without success before updating R. Thanks for the help DWin!

Comment: Actually, in addition the select() method I needed is defined in 2 packages (MASS and AnnotationDBi), so make sure to use AnnotationDBi::select()

Comment: I actually finally figured out the problem. It wasn't in the patched version at all. Turns out I had another R application (the Shiny app that displayed the data generated by the other app) that was calling the library(hash) which also defines a keys() function. So again, it was a function name conflict. The best way to solve this is again to prepend the package on the keys() function: AnnotationDBi::keys(). Another point for object-oriented programming in my opinion.

Comment: Better if you post this as an answer for future readers!